# Best Way to Select Numeric Values from 1 - 500 in Android Application?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I'm currently developing an android app and one of the features is to select numerical values of large ranges. What is the best way to allow the user to select the number from, a spinner (android version of a dropdownlist) or a picker (mainly used to select time and date)? I need to ensure high efficiency in the app, so that users do not need to do much to get the number.

Answer (score 1):

use a validated `EditText` (with numbers keyboard hint) or , Use three pickers for each digit.

Answer (score 0):

use a validated autocomplete bind value with it and when user write text it give suggestion to pick value.